# JQuery Masonry not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I have the code posted in JSFiddler:

http://jsfiddle.net/xWWG8/

I cant seem to get it to work.  I had a similar problem once, but the solution to that was just a silly self closing script tags.  But I just cant seem to find what is wrong with this code.

also, How would I move the bottom div (The one with the text "here is some...") to the right of the other 2 divs using masonry?

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/NCMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="cntHeader" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            var columns = 2, setColumns = function () { columns = $(window).width() > 640 ? 3 : $(window).width() > 320 ? 2 : 1; };
            setColumns();
            $(window).resize(setColumns);
            $('#main').masonry({ itemSelector: '.blob', columnWidth: function (containerWidth) { return containerWidth / columns; } });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <div id="main">
    <div class="blob">
         <p class="body-text">What good is a race if you dont finish in style :)
      </p>
    </div><br />
    <div class="blob">  
        <div class="test">Test</div>
        <div class="test">Test</div>
        <div class="test">Test</div>
        <iframe  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NHPaXjJgzXo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" class="media"></iframe>
        <iframe width="75" height="75" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NHPaXjJgzXo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" class="media"></iframe>
        <iframe width="75" height="75" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NHPaXjJgzXo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" class="media"></iframe>
    </div>
     <div class="blob">
         Here is some more text.  I am trying to get this blob in to a new column on the right o0f the other 2 blobs
     </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, after some fiddling I *think* I have managed to solved your problem. First thing first, some housekeeping with your code... ;)

## Some issues with the original fiddle:

1. Masonry.js is not linked — you should link an externally-hosted JS file, I have used a [CDN-hosted Masonry (v3.1.2)](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.1.2/masonry.pkgd.js)
2. jQuery library is not loaded. Remember to load it
3. You are nesting two `$(window).load` function, because JSFiddle automatically wraps it for you
4. `containerWidth` is not a declared variable.

---

## Suggested improvements

It seems that you are attempting to use the parent container width to calculate the number of columns, based on the screensize. I offer you a better solution:

- Determine number of columns by adjusting the width of `.blob`, by listening on the screen resolution based on CSS media queries &mash; if you want 3 columns, set width to `33.33333%`. 2 columns, you can use `50%` and etc.
- Remove the 5px padding from `#main`, as it interferes with percentage calculation.
- Declare `box-sizing: border-box` on the `.blob` children, so that the width declared in CSS includes the padding (which you have used 10px).

For your JS, simply select **onLoad** on the left panel. You don't have to wrap it again with `$(window).load(function(){...}` because it's already done for you. So for your JS, just use:

```
$('#main').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.blob'
});
```

**Really, it's that simple!** For your CSS, I have made some changes - check out the new fiddle linked below. The changes are described earlier above in my answer.

Here is a working example of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/xWWG8/12/

---

## Other notes

**Note:** You might want to look into some jQuery-powered options of dealing with resizing iframes and other embedded content, since it is evident from my (partially) fixed solution that your embedded YouTube video is overflowing. I would recommend implementing Chris Coiyer's [FitVid.js](http://fitvidsjs.com/) for that purpose.

With regards to a comment in your CSS file that commented out a `float` property because it causes the parent to collapse, simply use `overflow: hidden` on `.blob` when you are floating any of its child.